# Cypress testing command doAdministratorLogin fails

Tags: cms-testing, cypress

I'm trying to run the original Joomla Cypress tests here:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/5.0-dev/tests/System

After Joomla gets successfully installed I always get this message when the next test starts:

```
CypressError: This session already exists. You may not create a new session with a previously used identifier. If you want to create a new session with a different setup function, please call `cy.session()` with a unique identifier other than **["admin","adminadminadmin","back"]**.

https://on.cypress.io/session
      at Context.session (http://127.0.0.1:8000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:133555:72)
      at wrapped (http://127.0.0.1:8000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:138644:43)
  From Your Spec Code:
          at Context.eval(webpack:///./tests/System/support/commands.js:57:12)
```

I'm using the same Helper Functions Joomla uses for Backend Login:
https://github.com/joomla-projects/joomla-cypress

This is the command Joomla uses for picking up the session:

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('doAdministratorLogin', (originalFn, username, password, useSnapshot = true) => {
  // Ensure there are valid credentials
  const user = username ?? Cypress.env('username');
  const pw = password ?? Cypress.env('password');

  // Do normal login when no snapshot should be used
  if (!useSnapshot) {
    // Clear the session data
    Cypress.session.clearAllSavedSessions();

    // Call the normal function
    return originalFn(user, pw);
  }

  // Do login through the session
  return cy.session([user, pw, 'back'], () => originalFn(user, pw), { cacheAcrossSpecs: true });
});
```

So i minimized everything like seen here:

```
describe('First Admin Login', () => {
    it('First Admin Login', () => {
        cy.doAdministratorLogin('admin', 'adminadminadmin', false);
    })
    it('Second Admin Login (session based)', () => {
        cy.doAdministratorLogin();
    });
})
```

The second admin login always fails like described above.